# Match one substring and replace another on same line

Tags: sed

I want to change all `true` values to `false` for all lines that contain `should-log` substring, the input files contain other lines to but are not mentioned in this snippet:

```
logging.ap.should-log-headers = true
logging.ap.should-log-password = true
logging.api.should-log-headers = true
logging.httpbin.should-log-headers = true
logging.httpbin.should-log-password = true
logging.copy.should-log-headers = false
logging.copy.should-log-password = false
logging.test.should-log-headers = false
logging.test.should-log-password = false
logging.-test.should-log-password = true
logging.hu.should-log-headers = true
logging.madf.should-log-headers = true
logging.madf.should-log-password = true
logging.api-f-002.should-log-headers = true
logging.f.should-log-headers = true
logging.f-d.should-log-headers = true
logging.f-d.should-log-password = true
logging.copy-d.should-log-headers = false
logging.copy-d.should-log-password = false
logging.d.should-log-headers = false
logging.d.should-log-password = false
logging.e.should-log-headers = true
logging.e.should-log-password = true
```

what I am trying:

```
sed -i -E '/should-log=/{s/true/false/;}' infile
```

but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong, how should I do it?

Comment: I don't see any input line having `=` after `should-log` (also, you don't need `{}` grouping for single command after the address)

Comment: @Sundeep `sed -i -E '/should-log/s/true/false/'` after you suggestions, works can you please make that as an answer so I can accept it, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`should-log=` doesn't match any of the given input lines. You could use something like `should-log-` or `should-log.*=` or `should-log-.*=`.

Also, the `{}` grouping isn't needed for single command after the address.

Answer (score 1):

Regex engine searches for matches from left to right. When you write `should-log=`, the search starts at the start of string and `s` is searched for. Once `s` is found, the regex engine checks the next char and if it is `h`, it goes on checking and once it gets to `=` after finding `g`, there is a failure, no `=` after `g`.

***You need to make sure you allow the regex engine to actually get to (=*consume*) the part of the string you want***.

Since after `g` you need to get to the first `=`, it is logical to match any zero or more chars other than `=`, so you can use

```sh
sed -i -E 's/(should-log[^=]*= *).*/\1false/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FZNPOz). The POSIX ERE (see `-E`) regex matches

- `(` - start of a capturing group with ID 1 (its value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `should-log` - a `should-log` sting
  - `[^=]*` - a negated bracket expression matching zero or more chars other than `=`
  - `=` - a `=` char
  - `*`
- `)` - end of the capturing group
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Note that `sed -i -E '/should-log[^=]*=/s/true/false/' file` is less precise as it [might replace](https://ideone.com/qDTv5j) `true` that is not after `should-log[^=]*=`.